# Pass non-string argument to r function and use it inside this function as is

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am a bit confused with the way arguments are transmitted to r function, and the associated syntax (quoting, substituting, evaluating, calling, expressions, "...", ...) .

Basically, what I need to do is to pass arguments in a function using only their name, but without using the type "character".

This is a (not working) illustration of what I would like to do

```
require(dplyr)

test <- function(x) select(iris, DesiredFunction(x))

test(Species)
```

I am also interested in general resources about the possibilities to pass arguments to functions.

Thank you,

François

UPDATE

The following is working

```
require(dplyr)
test <- function(x) select_(iris, substitute(x))
test(Species)
```

Is there a way to do this but with "select" instead of "select_" ?

Or in other words, what is the inverse operation for quoting ?

Comment: What s the `DesiredFunction`?

Comment: I think you should start reading the [non-standard evaluation article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) on CRAN. This deals with the general concepts around using `dplyr` like this.

Comment: DesiredFunction is the function I would like to use if it exist. It would pass "Species" to the function "select"